# GitLab does not automatically mirror if pusher are not the owner

Tags: github, gitlab, mirror

So I mirrored a repository from GitHub using the `CI/CD from external repo` option. In GitHub, I am not the owner of that repo but a collaborator. I noticed whenever the owner `git push` the repo, GitLab will automatically mirror. But when I, the collaborator, `git push` the repo, the mirroring will not start automatically. Instead, I need to manually click the update button.